# android:why the method offsetTopandBottom() doesn't call the onDraw()?

Tags: android

I have a guess about it, but don't know if it's right.I think this is because method `offsetTopandBottom()` has just changed the property of view,which is ok just within gpu.If the contents of view changed, then it will call the callbacks,such as `onLayout()`,`onMeasure()`,`onDraw()`,etc.Is that right?

Answer (score 0):

we can find mRenderNode.offsetTopAndBottom(offset); in the code.So view.offsetTopAndBottom direct influence on RenderNode of the view.Invalidate not called here